# Ruby and unexpected OpenSSL version after 1.0.1 to 1.0.2 upgrade

Tags: ruby, nginx, openssl, ubuntu-14.04, upgrade

I was trying to upgrade openssl to 1.0.2 from 1.0.1 using openssl source https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz 
and follow the process as given below:

```
$ sudo apt-get install make
$ wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz 
$ tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2j.tar.gz
$ cd openssl-1.0.2j
$ sudo ./config
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl`
$ openssl version -v
```

`openssl` was upgraded.

After that I was trying to install ruby with following commands

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y ruby2.1 ruby2.1-dev
```

ruby was pointing to old version of openssl

I was trying this to check the version:

```
$ ruby -r openssl -e 'puts OpenSSL::OPENSSL_VERSION'
```

it was showing openssl version 1.0.1

while when I was checking

```
$ openssl version -v
```

it shows 1.0.2

Same issue was with nginx but I solved it by using

```
--with-openssl=/tmp/openssl-1.0.2j
```

during ./config

So, Please help me out of this issue. What is the perfect way to upgrade openssl by taking care of dependencies?

Comment: Your `config` of OpenSSL should include `-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib`. Otherwise, `openssl` will link to the wrong version at runtime, too. `ldd` will tell you. You need to tell Ruby to use your OpenSSL located at `/usr/local/ssl`. Its not clear what the Ruby configuration is with respect to OpenSSL. Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: i tried as your told.

Comment: i tried as your told.  steps: $ cd openssl-1.0.2j  $ ./config -Wl,-rpath=/usr/local/ssl/lib  $ make   $ readelf -d ./libssl.so | grep -i rpath 
it shows $: command not found

Comment: after that i tried to run $ make install and than $ ldd /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so      it was showing ldd: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so: No such file or directory

Comment: I tried to install  $ sudo apt-get install elfutils

Comment: And repeated the same process after $ readelf -d ./libssl.so | grep -i rpath it shows libssl.so file is not found

Comment: Please reply as soon as possible